# Trying to pass the variable "data" from "on_select" to the Text-Widget

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global-variables

I am trying to pass the variable "data" from "on_select" to the Text-Widget. So that the content of the file someone imports changes by selecting the item on the listbox. But I'm still a very beginner and don't know how to pass the value of data. Could anyone please help me here? Thank you!

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
root=Tk()
data = "Bitte eine Datei importieren."

class View(Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Listbox.__init__(self, master, width=75, selectmode=SINGLE)

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self._master = master

        frame1 = Frame(self._master)
        frame1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=5,expand=True)

        self._Listbox=View(frame1)
        self._Listbox.pack(side = TOP,fill=BOTH, expand = True,pady=20)

        menubar = Menu(self._master)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Importieren", command = self.file_open)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Beenden", command = quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)
        self._master.config(menu=menubar)

    def on_select(event):
        filename = self._Listbox.get(self._Listbox.curselection()[0])

        global data
        data = "Test"

        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            data = f.readlines()
        print data

    self._Listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)      

    def file_open(self):
        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        self._Listbox.insert(END,filename)

T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, data)
print data           

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c=Controller(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The controller needs to know about the text widget in order to control it. So, pass the text widget when creating the controller.

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        self.text = text
        ...
    def on_select(self, event):
        ...
        self.text.insert("end", data)
        ...
...
T = Text(...)
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c=Controller(root, T)
```